# Installer mounted as /cdrom

Tags: system-installation, mount, hard-drive, startup, unmount

I realize that this has been asked before but none of the solutions have worked for me. I have an external hard drive that I am using to install Ubuntu alongside windows. When it gets to a certain point in the installation setup, it says that it cannot unmount `/cdrom`.

I know that this is because the installer is mounted at `/cdrom` (I am running a live session) but I dont know how to change this. I cant just remount it because the computer is running off of it. The dialog that says 'cannot unmount /cdrom' has buttons to let me go back or try again but neither of them do anything.

How do I set it up to mount at a different location before startup?

Some solutions that I have already tried:

- remounting as normal
- editing mount options in Disks (will not work because computer resets)
- A variety of commands found here and other forums

I will write any others that I can think of

Comment: Could you list the solutions you've already tried so we don't go off on a wild goose chase?